# Python Selenium returning to a previous line and throwing error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My code throws an error that I can't understand. It proceeds normally but after one instruction, returns to the previous instruction and throw a error because its selector is not more present on screen.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-child(2) > a') # Line that is causing error
button.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'selector')))
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "menuPrincipal_divLinks3")
element.click()
```

The line that is causing my error works the first time but somehow fails later. Error code:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > a"}
```

I am expecting that the code proceeds without error.

Comment: It isn't returning to a previous line.  It's not an immediate error to have a failed search, but if you try to USE that result (as in `button.click()`), that's a failure.  It seems clear that the element is not present.

Comment: But the button is really being clicked, only after the error appears

Comment: @TimRoberts In this case, it would be an immediate error because of a failed search. `.find_element()` throws immediately if the element is not found.

Comment: Your code is not going backwards... you are misunderstanding something. Show us a [mcve] so we can try the code for ourselves and find the issue.

Comment: Then which line gets the error?  Please show the whole traceback.

Comment: it's pretty clear that the very first line gets the error where it's unable to locate the element by the given selector.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.